# How to enable adjustable tiling on Portrait mode?

Tags: window-management, window-decoration

I was wondering what should I do to enable this when I rotate the screen (I do this often with keyboard shortcuts for *xrandr -o normal* and *xrandr -o left*). The feature works [only on Landscape mode](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*vinLDLc_TjAKz_ooxXRErg.gif), but not on portrait (similar to what you can do on [latest Android versions](https://youtu.be/oahar1FinP8?t=73)).

In other words: I want that when I rotate my screen, to be able to maximize windows and that they stick on an upper and lower half, and that to be able to adjust the split size just like in landscape mode.

And I'm using latest Juno eOS release. Any clue?

[image: window tiling where?]

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with editing few lines in Gala, the window manager? [link](https://github.com/elementary/gala)

Comment: Have you found anything about this?

Comment: Till now, nothing. Seems we'll have to wait the devoloper to release this feature one day...